# Simple Ruby template engine

Tags: ruby, templates, web

I tried to write a simple web template engine in Ruby that takes an input, a JSON file and produces an HTML file. The content to be replaced will have a syntax like this `<* place_holder *>`.

For example, the template looks like this:

```
<body>    
<* EACH students student *>
  <* student.name *>
  <* EACH student.nicknames nickname *>
    <p><* nickname *></p>
  <* ENDEACH *>    
<* ENDEACH *>
</body>
```

The JSON is:

```
   {
  "page": {
    "title": "Templating Example"
  },
  "teacher": {
    "name": "Mr. John"
  },
  "students": [
    { "name": "Bruce Wayne", "nicknames": ["Batman"] },
    { "name": "Peter Parker", "nicknames": ["Spidey", "Spiderman", "Spider-Man"] }
  ]
}
```

and the output will be:

```
<body>
<h1>Mr. John</h1>

  Bruce Wayne

    <p>Batman</p>


  Peter Parker

    <p>Spidey</p>

    <p>Spiderman</p>

    <p>Spider-Man</p>
```

What I have :

```
def replace_loop(lop_arr,json_data,somefile)

regex = Regexp.new(/\<\* .* \*\>/)      


lop = false
key = ""
size_lop = 0
length = lop_arr.size - 1   

for i in 0..length # go line by line 
  # check if it is loop indicator, replace with blank
  if lop_arr[i].include?("<* EACH") 
    lop = true
    new_content = lop_arr[i].gsub(lop_arr[i], "")
    somefile.puts new_content

   # check if it is endloop indicator, replace with blank
  elsif lop_arr[i].include?("<* ENDEACH")
    new_content = lop_arr[i].gsub(lop_arr[i], "")
    somefile.puts new_content
    lop = false
  else
    if lop # if inside the loop
      blank = lop_arr[i].gsub(regex, "")
      somefile.puts blank   
      # separate the content to find value in JSON data                 
      replacement = lop_arr[i].match(regex)
      replacement_content = replacement.to_s.match(/ .* /).to_s.strip
      arr_data = replacement_content.split(".")  
       # arr_data:   [student, name]
      arr_data_length = arr_data.length - 1
      data = ""
      # because the JSON file contains the plural of the object, so I use pluralzie to find the    value
      json_data[arr_data.first.pluralize].each do |ele|
        for j in 1..arr_data_length
            data = ele[arr_data[j]]
            puts data
        end
        somefile.puts data
      # somefile.puts "\n"
      end
    end
  end
```

This will only print out all the students name, I don't know how to replace the inner loop to put student's nicknames

Comment: Please show your try, and explain what is going wrong with it. It will help someone to give you an answer.

Comment: You could look at the [ERB source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb) for inspiration if you want